# Как при помощи командлета Powershell Invoke-WebRequest загрузить файл боту telegram bot api?

Tags: powershell, бот, telegram

```
Invoke-WebRequest -InFile 'C:\test.apk' -Method Post -ContentType 'multipart/form-data' ('https://api.telegram.org/botXXX/sendDocument?chat_id=xxx&document')
```

При таком запросе ошибка:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: "Как при помощи командлета Powershell Invoke-WebRequest загрузить файл боту telegram bot api?" Что тут непонятного?

Comment: Непонятно то, что вы попытались сделать, и в чем именно у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: Пытался отправить своему боту в телеграме файл, при помощи Powershell командлета Invoke-WebRequest, при отправке получаю ошибку: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Answer (score 1):

> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Предположу, что проблема в том, что PowerShell не может проверить валидность сертификата. Попробуйте добавить следующий код перед вызовом `Invoke-Webrequest`:

```
# Make invoke-webrequest to ignore cert check
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

Мне оно помогло, правда, при обратной ситуации — нужно было скачать с https в обход проверки сертификата. Не знаю, насколько оно работает в обратную сторону.

Comment: Та же ошибка...